# parsing text using regular expression

Tags: perl, parsing

I have some texts and I would like to extract the lines with the following pattern.

```
string1(string2,string3,int)
```

I am using perl to parse I could only write code for the rule for string1(string2)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$txt='A (A, B, 49997 )';

$re1='((?:[a-z][a-z]+))';   # Word 1
$re2='.*?'; # Non-greedy match on filler
$re3='(\\(.*\\))';  # Round Braces 1

$re=$re1.$re2.$re3;
if ($txt =~ m/$re/is)
{
$word1=$1;
$rbraces1=$2;
print "($word1) ($rbraces1) \n";
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number of elements in parentheses beforehand, you can match each element easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $txt='A (B, C, 49997 )';

my $id  = qr/([a-z]+)/i;
my $int = qr/([1-9][0-9]*)/;


if (my @matches = $txt =~ /$id \s* \(  $id , \s* $id , \s* $int \s* \)/x ) {
    print "($_)\n" for @matches;
}
```

If the identifier can be repeated any number of times, you can still match using `( $id , \s* )+`, but only the last capture group will be returned. In such a case, extract the whole list and use `split /,\s*/`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $txt='A (B, C, D, E, F, 49997 )';

my $id   = qr/[a-z]+/i;
my $int  = qr/[1-9][0-9]*/;
my $list = qr/$id (?: , \s* $id)*/x;


if (my @matches = $txt =~ /($id) \s* \( ($list) , \s* ($int) \s* \)/x ) {
    splice @matches, 1, 1, split /,\s*/, $matches[1];
    print "($_)\n" for @matches;
}
```